# How to Access SASS/SCSS variables in your React Components inline style

Tags: reactjs, sass

Let's say I have a button style in my JSX like this

```
const btnStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: '$green-d1',
  border: 0,
};
```

how can I access the `$green-d1` variable from my scss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. With [Interoperable CSS](https://github.com/css-modules/icss)'s `:export` feature

```scss
:export {
  greenD1: $green-d1;
}
```

```js
import styles from "./styles.scss";

const btnStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: styles.greenD1,
  border: 0,
};
```

For this to work, you either need to use [CSS module](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/styling/css-modules/#what-is-a-css-module) or configure [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#separating-interoperable-css-only-and-css-module-features) correctly by setting `mode` to `"icss"`.

#### 2. With a CSS variable

```scss
:root {
  --green-d1: #{$green-d1};
}
```

```js
const styles = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
const greenD1 = styles.getPropertyValue('--green-d1');

const btnStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: greenD1,
  border: 0,
};
```

Comment: Woah. I had no idea this was a thing.

Comment: Also, did you mean `styles.module.scss` instead?

Comment: @GROVER. Not necessarily, I use `.scss` files and it works as long as the css-loader is correctly configured in webpack. It's the property `mode` that need to be set to `icss`.

Comment: Here is the link to the doc for that: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#separating-interoperable-css-only-and-css-module-features